# Is there a list of coins that are bip-32 compatible?

Tags: altcoin, bip32-hd-wallets, secp256k1

BIP 32 allows me to derive keys based off a root key pair, and all these keys will be on the secp256k1 curve. That means I'll be able to use BIP 32 for other coins that are also based on your curve.

Is there a list of well know coins and the curve they are based on? My spot check shows that most seem to be, but I'm looking for a more comprehensive list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Bip-32 allows me to dereive keys based off a root key pair, and all these keys will be on the secp256k1 curve.

This is actually not true. The [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) proposal simply states that (emphasis mine):

> In the rest of this text we will ***assume*** the public key cryptography used in Bitcoin, namely elliptic curve cryptography using the field and curve parameters defined by secp256k1

In reality, it can be used for any curve, as evidenced by the fact that both Monero and Zcash support BIP32 backed derivations, but use different curves.

If you wish to see a list of coins that follow the BIP32/39/44 system, you can check the coin type list maintained by Satoshi Labs at [SLIP-0044](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md)